# Extend a non-GUI framework by a GUI

Tags: user-interface, design-patterns

I have a "framework" which does its job if I use it via code. That's good because not all systems the framework will run on have the graphical stuff installed.

Now I want to create a graphical user interface for this framework. Because a big, self managed composite of the framework is finally running, I don't want to create a parallel GUI hierarchy and reimplement all the self managing stuff for the GUI as well as organize the . Indeed my idea is to create just an extension for each class, e. g. called `gui` which can be included in the main window later. Hence, I would sketch it as follows:

[image]

In this illustration I don't like the multiple inheritance. As the example with `m2()` shows it introduces some issues. Here, it's the question: "Which `m(2)` is executed by `ConcreteGui`, the updated one from `AbstractGui` or the outdated one from `AbstractClass` which came from `ConcreteClass`?"

Which approach or design pattern can I use?

**EDIT:**

Let's assume the following given framework (it's a language-independent problem and Python serves only as illustration).

```
class AbstractClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 23
        self.b = 42
    def m1(self):
        return self.a + self.b
    def m2(self):
        self.b += 1
        return self.a * 2

class ConcreteClass1(AbstractClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()      # constructor of AbstractClass
        self.c = 13
        self.d = 7
    def m3(self):
        return self.a - self.d
    def m4(self):
        self.a += 1
        return self.b / self.c
```

Now, each attribute shall get a GUI-widget as user-friendly representation (showing current value) as well as interface (setting a value). For that, I don't want to rewrite *all* methods to use the particular widget instead of the attribute. The added widgets should be transparent to all already implemented methods.

Comment: Is the 'm2()' in 'AbstractGui' any different to 'AbstractClass'?  if you are only extending the 'AbstractGui' with '#gui' then why not implement this as interface on both concreteGui (possibly with an dependency injection)?

Comment: Yes, `m2()` of `AbstractGui` is different to `AbstractClass`'s one. It's also possible (or even more probable) that `m2()` is redefined in `ConcreteClass` instead of `AbstractGui`. Then `#gui` can be a interface which is implemented by `AbstractGui` and `ConcreteGui`, but how do the attributes `a` and `b` of `ConcreteGui` become properties?

Comment: Why not remove the 'AbstractGui' and replace with 'IGui' or similar that contains the "+a and +b that properties of widget and #gui" and implement those in each ConcreteGui classes and also you would be able to override the +m2() from AbstractClass.

Comment: But it's neither efficient nor maintainable to _copy_ the same "+a, +b and m2() implementation" in each (of hundreds?) `ConcreteGui`s. I want to reuse the generation and linkage of widget<->`a`/`b` as well as the overwritten `m2()`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Proposed Design]

You cannot derive from both ConcreteClass and AbstractGUIClass, you may have to keep the GUI implementation separate and inject them into ConcreteGuiClass

```
public class ConcreteClassGui1 : ConcreteClass1 {

    private IGuiSpecificOperations _guiSpecificOperations;

    public ConcreteClassGui1(IGuiSpecificOperations guiSpecificOperations){

        _guiSpecificOperations = guiSpecificOperations;

        SetSomeGuiProperties();
    }

    ~ConcreteClassGui1(){

    }

    public override Method2()
    {
        // specific implementation
    }

    private void SetGuiProperties()
    {
        _guiSpecificOperations.PropertyGuiA = "Test";
        _guiSpecificOperations.PropertyGuiB = 10;
    }

}

public class ConcreteClassGui2 : ConcreteClass2 {


    private IGuiSpecificOperations _guiSpecificOperations;

    public ConcreteClassGui2(IGuiSpecificOperations guiSpecificOperations){

        _guiSpecificOperations = guiSpecificOperations;
    }

    ~ConcreteClassGui2(){

    }

    public override Method2()
    {
        // specific implementation
        _guiSpecificOperations.PropertyGuiA = "Text";
        _guiSpecificOperations.PropertyGuiB = 10;
    }

}

public class GuiSpecificOperationImplementation : IGuiSpecificOperations {

    public GuiSpecificOperationImplementation(){

    }

    ~GuiSpecificOperationImplementation(){

    }

    public string PropertyGuiA{ get; set;}

    public int PropertyGuiB {get; set;}

}

    public interface IGuiSpecificOperations  
   {    
    public string PropertyGuiA{ get; set;}

    public int PropertyGuiB {get; set;}
   }
```

Also noticed that the implementation of the IGuiSpecificOperations has been injected into the ConcreteGuiClass rather than deriving them.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it. I have to reimplement all methods using `PropertyX` to use `_guiSpecificOperations.PropertyGuiX` instead anyway? I added an example to my question which hopefully sketches my concern more clearly.